# (MVC Calculator) How to maintain the value of how many times an option from index.jsp is selected?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

code of body from my index.jsp:

```
    1st Number: <input type="first" name="num1" size="15"required>
                <select name="operator" size="1">
                <option>+
                <option>-
                <option>*
                <option>/
                </select>
    2nd Number: <input type="second" name="num2" size="15"required>
```

the code from my model (CalcClass.java):

```
public int getAdd() {
            int a = 0;
    if(operator.equals("+"))
    {
        a++;
    }
    return a;
}
        public int getSubtract() {
            int s = 0;
    if(operator.equals("-"))
    {
        s++;
    }
    return s;
}
            public int getMultiply() {
            int m = 0;
    if(operator.equals("*"))
    {
        m++;
    }
    return m;
}
                public int getDivide() {
            int d = 0;
    if(operator.equals("/"))
    {
        d++;
    }
    return d;
}
```

code of my servlet (CalcServlet.java):

```
        int add = cc.getAdd();
        int minus = cc.getSubtract();
        int multiply = cc.getMultiply();
        int divide = cc.getDivide();
        request.setAttribute("a", add);
        request.setAttribute("s", minus);
        request.setAttribute("m", multiply);
        request.setAttribute("d", divide);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
        view.include(request, response);
```

code of my result.jsp:

```
       String add = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("a"));
        String s = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("s"));
        String m = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("m"));
        String d = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("d"));


            out.print(" + " + " = " + add);

            out.print(" - " + " = " + s);

            out.print(" * " + " = " + m);

            out.print(" / " + " = " + d);

           <a href ="index.jsp" >BACK</a>
```

my problem is that i can only count the used option ONLY from my first click of submit button, after pressing my BACK link (href=index.jsp) in my result.jsp to go for another submit button, the value of the counted option(operator) from my first click is resetting into 0.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe I just don't understand the bigger picture but all your method variables have local scope. So, how would `getAdd` ever return anything other than `1` (or `0` when `operator != +`)?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the one possible bug is that:
You had **initialized the int variables** in your methods. Let's say getAdd() method. So, Every time you call getAdd() method, variable 'a' is set to 0 and it overrides the previous value.

This bug is same for all the methods as well.

You should declare those variable as **'Instance variable' of class not a local variable inside method**.

Correct it and check it again.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you said :

> after pressing my BACK link (href=index.jsp) in my result.jsp to go
>   for another submit button

what I can notice that you move from page to another page and the scope of your 
parameter is request scope because you put :

```
        request.setAttribute("a", add);
        request.setAttribute("s", minus);
        request.setAttribute("m", multiply);
        request.setAttribute("d", divide);
```

so when you move to another page the value will be destroyed , you need to do it with session scope

```
 request.getsession().setattribute("a", add);
 request.getsession().setattribute("s", minus);
 request.getsession().setattribute("m", multiply);
 request.getsession().setattribute("d", divide);
```

Now if you move to index.jsp and you call for example

```
${a}
```

you will find the right value

and you said :

> the value of the counted option(operator) from my first click is
>   resetting into 0
>   to solve this problem I suggest to :

1 / the values are destroyed and the method getAdd() for example initialise a to 0 
you must change it to (also b,c,d) to parameter of you class

```
public class CalcClass{
private int a=0; 
//...
}
```

2 /  In your index.jsp you change the value of inputs(a,b,c,d) to  .

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="${a}"/>
......
```

there is many problems in your code and there is important things that you didn't show to us I hope this will help you to solve some problems